# Simple PHP - Doing Maths and Displaying an answer in PHP?

Tags: php, math

I am in Opencart and trying to display a price that has been divided by 1000 then times by 38. I have two files, product.php and product.tpl The tpl file is the front end and php file is the back end.

In the php file I have:

```
                if($special>0){
                    $lease_price = (($special/1000)*38);
                    } else {
                    $lease_price = (($price/1000)*38);
                    }
                    $lease_price = $this->currency->format($lease_price);
```

and in the tpl file I have:

```
                    <p>
                        <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
                        <b>Lease To Buy Price:</b>
                        <span><?php if($price>500){ ?>
          <?php echo $lease_price; ?>
          <?php } else { echo 'NA'; } ?></span>                     
                    </p>
```

The $special tag is the price of the product when on offer and the $price tag is the normal price.

Here's the page I'm trying to implement this on: http://www.framec.co.uk/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=50

This doesn't seem to work; it only shows NA. Does anyone know what could be the issue here?
Thanks :)

Comment: So what is the question / issue again?

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear. The code shown above isn't working, it's just displaying NA. I'm wondering if the php code is incorrect? If i'm using the wrong tags or any incorrect code?

Comment: Is the PHP file referenced correctly in the tpl file?

Comment: your divided price does not complete the statement `>500` so you go to the else statement `'NA'` exmpl as shown on the site `(612.00 /1000)x38 = 23.256`

Comment: The file should be referenced correctly as it pulls other information from it correctly.

Comment: The >500 should reference the original price, so if that price is less than 500, show $lease_price which will be the original price divided by 1000 times by 38. Is it at the moment meaning that if the calculated price is less then 500 it's showing NA?

Comment: @AdamStevens that part should be fine, this is the output of the above posted code if recreated: `Lease To Buy Price: 23.256`

Comment: Can you somehow show us how does `$price` get its value? Or try an `echo $price;` as an error checking?

Comment: Okay so that's all right, the 23.256 is correct. I think what the issue is that the php code in the .php document has been entered in the wrong place.  Would I be able to just put it at the end of the document and it work? Or is there a specific header I need to put it under?

Comment: @AlexSzabó Do you know how I could do this in the tpl file?

Comment: @AdamStevens can you please amend your code in the tpl file to `<span><?php echo $price; ?></span> ` to see what value does `$price` have? Also, If you put your PHP code for example at the very bottom of the PHP page (just before `?>`) it should be fine.